# How to make style for XamDataGrid Fields to set property in the converters

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I want to make a ***style*** for fields of **XamDataGrid** to set the **AllowEdit** property of the fields in the ***converter*** using some conditions.
I am trying with this but not working for me.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:Field}">
     <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="AllowEdit"  Value="{Binding Path=Field, Source={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource FieldsEditableConverter}}">
            </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
 </Style>
```

Please suggest some code.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics said : "Once WPF Styles are in use, you cannot modify them."

Since I was looking for slightly the same thing (XamDataGrid, Field, Style, Setter modification of just access setter programmatically) but I wasn't able to. I've found the following information :

This exception has nothing to do with Infragistics controls.  Once WPF Styles are in use, you cannot modify them.  If you want to programmatically create Styles, you should create them from scratch, and not try to modify existing Style objects.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/13909.aspx

Despite the fact that you can not modify it dynamically, so, on my specific case, I finally used x:Name of Style used by the targeted setter when required : so just before it has to modify the list (CanExecute).

This is how my code looks like :

C# :

```
var cm = uc.Resources["fiContextMenu"] as ContextMenu;
foreach(MenuItem mi in cm.Items)
    if(mi.Header.Equals("Remove File"))
        mi.IsEnabled = false; //Disallow remove when empty list
```

Xaml :

```
<igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource fiContextMenu}" />
```